# How to maximise efficiency of JSONParser here?

Tags: java, multithreading

*I'm an amazing noob when it comes to threading, honestly. This is literally scampered together from the documentation, it's probably not even correct or necessary.*

I'm working with a class I've created for fetching data from Mojang's API, the methods are static and I'm unsure how to tackle the usage of a JSONParser (json-simple library) object.

My original code is on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Albioncode/2d58f0e4bda0a19130f8)
and the code I'm experimenting with is [here](https://gist.github.com/Albioncode/fae1ca0eac37aa81d647). In the second gist I've made the JSONParser static, noting that it wasn't thread-safe I used a `synchronized` getter to access it where needed, whereas in my first gist I'm creating a new `JSONParser` object for each method call.

Given that the code will often be run on another thread is the way I access the static JSONParser efficient or would I just be best sticking to the code in the first gist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the documentation of JSONParser](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.java), the class is not thread safe. So you either need proper locking or create one parser per thread.

A better design is probably to make all the public methods non-static and the `JSONparser` non-static as well. That way, you can create one `Fetcher` per thread.

OTOH, creating `JSONparser` is pretty cheap so unless you need millions of them per second, just create a new one per request.

Comment: @Albion my answer is not correct, please see this one.

Comment: Thanks! Willill stick with creating one per request given I'm anticipating a maximum of 50 per minute.